# Cluster Computing - Raspberry Pi and Julia

Tags: cluster, julia

I'm hoping to setup a cluster at home for a physics simulation I'm planning on running. However I don't have any real experience with HPC and I figured I should start with a small cluster just to learn all the basics. Currently my simulation is written in python using Numpy, but I'm hoping to rewrite it in Julia as I understand it's very good at setting up parallel computation. If I were to setup a small RPi cluster (3-4) RPis, would I be able to install BeoWulf and get a Julia program running on them without too much trouble? Any clarification/assistance would be much appreciated!